# How to parse and obtain a div element with a particular class using the SAX Parser

Tags: java, xml

This is a snippet of my XML file

```
<name>Jason</name>
<div class="title">Domain Architect</div>
```

How do I parse using SAX Parser and obtain the div element with the particular class "title" ?

I am able to parse and obtain all the div elements.
Is there a simple way to obtain the elements that are of a particular class only.

EDIT :

This is how my handler is :

```
DefaultHandler handler = new DefaultHandler() {

boolean bfname = false;
boolean bdesig = false;

public void startElement(String uri, String localName,String qName, 
            Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {



    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("name")) {
        bfname = true;
    }

    if((qName.equalsIgnoreCase("div"))) {
        bdesig = true;
    }


}

public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) throws SAXException {

    if (bfname) {
        System.out.println("Name : " + new String(ch, start, length));
        bfname = false;
    }

    if(bdesig) {
        System.out.println("Designation : " + new String(ch, start, length));
        bdesig = false;
    }

}

 };
```

Comment: Can you show the code you're currently using?  Since `startElement` has access to all the attributes of the relevant tag this should be a simple tweak to your existing approach.

Comment: You should be aware that you are not necessarily guaranteed to receive all the contiguous text content within an element in a single call to `characters`.  What you should do is start a buffer in `startElement` when you see a start tag you're interested in, append to that buffer in `characters`, then turn the complete buffer into a string in `endElement` as it's only when `endElement` is called that you know you have received all the characters between that element's start and end tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `startElement()` the class attribute can be evaluated from the `attributes`. You then could set a flag if there is an attribute `class` and you are interested in this particular class (its value). Reset the flag if you are not. Evaluate this flag in `characters` to retrieve the text contents of the element.

For small documents and non-critical performance you could use XPath to solve this in a more elegant way.